# SQL: Cross product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to determine how many people have purchased a pair of goods out of all distinct pairs of products that can exist. E.g. I have three products, A, B, C and I would like to determine how many % of customers bought A and B, B and C, and A and C out of the number of customers who own either product within each pair by country.

My table looks like the below.

```
 Customer | Country | Product
 1        |    US   |    A
 1        |    US   |    B
 2        |    CA   |    A
 2        |    CA   |    C
 3        |    US   |    A
 3        |    US   |    C
 4        |    US   |    B
 5        |    US   |    A
```

Note that a customer can only belong to one country.

My desired output is:

```
 Country | Pair |   %
 US      | A_B  |  25%    
 US      | B_C  |   0%
 US      | A_C  |  25%
 CA      | A_B  |   0%    
 CA      | B_C  |   0%
 CA      | A_C  | 100%
```

The % is essentially the ratio

```
(# of unique customers who bought Product1 and Product2)/
(# of unique customers who bought Product1 or Product2)
```

by country.

So for instance, in the US for `A_B` we have 4 customers who bought `A` or `B` but only 1 of these bought both `A` and `B` so the ratio is `1/4`.

Is there a nice solution to this which would scale if I had a large number, arbitrary number of pairs?

Comment: Do you need the output per country? Or what is the significance of "Note that a customer can only belong to one country."?

Comment: So, you have completely changed the question. All the answers below are now irrelevant. You should have created a new question, because as of now it seems that the answers do not produce the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want pairs that have a product, you can use a simple `join`:

```
select t1.product, t2.product, count(distinct customer)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.customer = t2.customer
group by t1.product, t2.product;
```

For all pairs, you can use this as a subquery and then join back to a list of all product pairs:

```
with pp as (
      select t1.product as product1, t2.product as product2, count(distinct customer) as cnt
      from t t1 join
           t t2
           on t1.customer = t2.customer
      group by t1.product, t2.product
     )
select p1.product, p2.product, pp.cnt
from (select distinct product from t) p1 cross join
     (select distinct product from t) p2 left join
     pp
     on pp.product1 = t1.product and pp.product2 = t2.product;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I couldn't find a way to change the query above to get my desired result so I have altered my question to encompass my entire goal.

Answer (score 0):

First, get all pairings of `Product`s using a `JOIN`. Then use `APPLY` to `COUNT` the `Customer`s who brought both `Product`:

```
WITH CteProduct AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Prod1 = t1.Product,
        Prod2 = t2.Product
    FROM tbl t1
    INNER JOIN tbl t2
        ON t1.Product < t2.Product
)
SELECT
    Parir = c.Prod1 + '_' + c.Prod2,
    Number = ISNULL(x.Number, 0)
FROM CteProduct c
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT 
        t.Customer,
        Number = COUNT(DISTINCT t.Country)
    FROM tbl t
    WHERE t.Product IN(c.Prod1, c.Prod2)
    GROUP BY t.Customer
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Product) = 2
    
) x;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/461882)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I be able tp change this to count by country and product  pair?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the requirement. Change `Number = COUNT(DISTINCT Customer)` to `Number = COUNT(DISTINCT Country)`

Comment: This seems the most straightforward. However, I don't think this will work as per my new edit as I'm not looking to count over countries. Please see my edit.